# .net - Accessing a pages global variables from a user control

Tags: c#, .net, user-controls, global-variables

I'd like to know if it's possible to access a page's global variables from a user control that is on that page.

```
 public partial class index : System.Web.UI.Page
  {
    FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)User.Identity;
    string custID = "some guid";
    string accID = "some guid";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
  }
```

This is just an example, my actual global variables are more complex custom configuration objects but it should be the same.

I'd like to access the variables from a user control. this would be helpful since I'd need to use the same objects on both the page and the user control and I don;t really want to have retrieve and store in in memory twice.

Anyone know if/how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Since user controls are meant to be encapsulated and reusable, you should be passing whatever data they require INTO them, not expecting to pull data from their parent page(s).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can. It is called passing the variables to the user control. Sure it is stored in memory more than once, but that is a bit of the "price" of keeping a separation of concerns and making reusable controls.

If the items are constants, you can store them as true globals and access via a static method in global.asax. If on a request basis, this won't work in a simple manner, but you can fashion it.

Now, for your not wanting to store in memory twice comment. I would not worry about this, as it is a small amount of information (1), especially since it will only last for the duration of the request (2). Not completely true, as GC does not fire immediately.

Answer (score 2):

If you are depending on this information over multiple controls, its best to have a UserControlBase that inherits from UserControl and then make your controls inherit from UserControlBase. Do the same with the Page classes. Then you can add the property to your BasePage. To reference in your UserControlBase just do...

```
protected UserInfo UserInfo 
{ 
    get 
    { 
        return ((BasePage)this.Page).UserInfo; 
    }
}
```